# How to open .xlsx files with POI SS?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to open .xlsx files with POI SS with this code (taken from http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ReadWriteWorkbook):

```
InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("workbook.xls");
//InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("workbook.xlsx");

Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
Row row = sheet.getRow(2);
Cell cell = row.getCell(3);
if (cell == null)
    cell = row.createCell(3);
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
cell.setCellValue("a test");

// Write the output to a file
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

and I get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
```

I add the xbean.jar to my library and to my run-time libraries.

how can I resolve this exception?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

### First: Fix the Exception

There are two solutions:

1. As Gagravarr already mentioned: you need dom4j to fix your exception.
2. As Jon already mentioned: you have to update your dependencies, so you don't need dom4j anymore.

If you're using Maven, you can add the necessary dependencies with: (Maybe check for newer versions at: [Maven Repository: org.apache.poi](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi))

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

### Then: Open the File

If you've fixed the exception, you can open your `file.xlsx` file with the following code:

```
String path = "Relative/Path/To/Your/File/file.xlsx";
File file = new File(path);

XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
// Use your sheet ...
```

### Further tips

- Like Gagravarr, I also recommend to use a file instead of a file input stream.
- If you want to open a certain sheet you can use `workbook.getSheet(String name);`
- If you don't know the relative path to your file according to your project, you can easily check it with `System.out.println("Relative path: " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));`

Regards, winklerrr

Answer (score 2):

You need dom4j, that's what the exception is telling you

You might want to look at [the components](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html) page on the POI website which lists the dependencies

Also, since you have a `File`, open directly with that, don't go via an `InputStream`. There's a section in the [Apache POI FAQ on that](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream), basically using a file is quicker and lower memory than buffering the whole thing via a stream!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't analyzed your error message, but after seeing the code, I see that there is something not correct.
The Wookbook is not work with *.xlsx (Office 2007 and after) files. So you have to use the XSSFWorkbook. You may want to change the wb initialization to:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
```

Answer (score 2):

This can help you.

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(pathOfYourXlsxFile);
                XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
                //Get first sheet from the workbook
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

For your Exception you have to put dom4j.jar to your classpath.You can find it [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1)

Comment: If you have a File, load directly from that! Don't go via the Stream, see the [POI documentation for more on why](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream)

Answer (score 0):

I realize the thread is old, but it led me today to the answer I needed for the same problem.

The docs on the page suggested above (i.e include dom4j.jar) say that's no longer necessary:

"The OOXML jars used to require DOM4J, but the code has now been changed to use JAXP and no additional dom4j jars are required."

I found that including the following resolved the problem:

```
poi-3.11-20141221.jar
poi-ooxml-3.11-20141221.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.11-20141221.jar
xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
```