# Apache POI - How to write to XLS in parts

Tags: apache-poi, xls

I use Apache POI and I have a lot of data that I want to write to *.xls file in parts.
Now I use:

```java
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
File tmpFile = new File("blabla.xls");
Workbook workbook = null;

try {
    for(int i = 1; i <= pageNumber; i++) {            
        workbook = xlsGenerator.generateWorkbook(someData, i);
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);
        workbook.write(fileOutputStream);
     }
}
```

But it doesn't work. It always replace old data instead of appending new data to workbook.  So, are there ways to write in parts?

Comment: You do know that the .xls file format doesn't support appending, don't you?

Comment: POI will allow you to open an XLS. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836965/how-to-open-xlsx-files-with-poi-ss